# Cannot establish network link between host and VM on Hyper-V

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I'm having trouble creating a network link between my Hyper-V host machine and its VM (both are running Windows 10).

I created an virtual external switch for both the host and VM so that both can access the internet and download programs and Windows updates, but I could not get them to communicate with each other directly. My research told me to create a virtual internal switch in Hyper-V and then have the devices be able to access each other that way (presumably by doing something like typing `\\host_machine_IP\c$` into an explorer window once the network connection had been made). But once I created the virtual internal switch and assigned static IP address to both the host and VM on it, I still could not ping the host from the VM, or vice versa.

Am I missing a step? Let me know what more details you guys need.

Answer (score 0):

By default you would have Windows Firewall blocking your communications until you confirm network profile to be other than Public. Try selecting a home\work network location profile via Control Panel > Network and Sharing canter. Or disable the firewall on the machine you try connecting to. Otherwise you should have no communication problem with the setup described, provided the subnet is the same for both machines.

Comment: Disabling the Windows firewall on the VM seems to have allowed me to access the C:\ drive on the host machine, so first, thank you very much! Second, I would like to know just which settings on the VM firewall were blocking the connection so that I can turn the firewall back on and simply omit such settings.

Comment: @ShadowFox Windows firewall doesn't block outbound traffic by default, so it shouldn't have affected your ability to connect to host machine from VM, there must be something else you have done that helped. Anything to do with file sharing is grouped in inbound firewall rules as "File and Printer Sharing" there are about nine rules for each firewall profile in this group.

Comment: yes, I believe you're right. I just turned the VM's Windows firewall back on and I still have connectivity. Is it possible that the VM just needed a few extra restarts/shutdowns after creation of the virtual internal switch?